# Calculating Night Shift duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking to calculate the Night_Start_Time, Night_Shift_End, Night_Shift_Duration

We have defined the Night_Shift_Start_Time = 22:00 hrs and Night_Shift_End_Time = 06:00 hrs.

To qualify for a night shift the employee should have worked minimum 30 minutes or else it will not be considered night shift

for eg;

- 03:00 pm - 22:29 pm, in this case, the employee work only 29 mins which
  are less than 30 mins it doesn't come under night shifts
- 03:00 pm -- 22:30 pm it is night shift as the employee worked for 30
  mins.
- 05:29 am -- 2:00 pm as the employee worked for 31 mins(06:00 - 05:29)
  it comes with night shift
- 05:31 am -- 2:00 pm as the employee worked for 29 mins night shift
  duration it can not consider as the night shift.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE #Shift 
  (Eid int,
   Shift_Start datetime,
   Shift_End datetime);
GO

INSERT INTO #Shift
VALUES
  (1,'20170522 20:00:00.000','20170523 06:00:00.000'),
  (2,'20170522 02:00:00.000','20170522 12:00:00.000'),
  (3,'20170522 23:00:00.000','20170523 08:00:00.000'),
  (4,'20170522 23:00:00.000','20170523 00:00:00.000'),
  (5,'20170522 00:00:00.000','20170522 05:00:00.000'),
  (6,'20170522 15:00:00.000','20170522 21:00:00.000');
GO
```

Expected output

```
Eid  Shift_Start              Shift_End                Night_Start_Time         Night_Shift_End          Night_Shift_Duration
1    2017-05-22 20:00:00.000  2017-05-23 06:00:00.000  2017-05-22 22:00:00.000  2017-05-23 06:00:00.000  8
2    2017-05-22 02:00:00.000  2017-05-22 12:00:00.000  2017-05-22 02:00:00.000  2017-05-22 06:00:00.000  4
3    2017-05-22 23:00:00.000  2017-05-23 08:00:00.000  2017-05-22 23:00:00.000  2017-05-23 06:00:00.000  7
4    2017-05-22 23:00:00.000  2017-05-23 00:00:00.000  2017-05-22 23:00:00.000  2017-05-23 00:00:00.000  1
5    2017-05-22 00:00:00.000  2017-05-22 05:00:00.000  2017-05-22 00:00:00.000  2017-05-22 05:00:00.000  5
6    2017-05-22 15:00:00.000  2017-05-22 21:00:00.000  NULL                     NULL                     0
```

Comment: sql server 2008..i used multicase statement  and currently working on  CASE WHEN Time > = 30mins  THEN CASE when shift_Time>= Night_Shift_Start then shift_Time WHEN shift_Time < Night_Shift_Start THEN Night_Shift_Start END ELSE Night_Shift_Start END as 'SHift_Start'

Comment: Is `0531 - 2201` considered a night shift?

Comment: Can an Employee work a shift for longer than 24 hours?

Comment: No employee cNNOT WORK MORE THAN 24 HRS

Comment: Should `Night_Shift_Duration" be `0` or `1` for a 29 minute shift?  What about for a `30` minute shift? What about for a `31` minute shift?

Comment: Night_Shift_Duration will be in H.M format. For 29 min shift = NULL, 30 min shift = 0.5 like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code...

```
SELECT Eid,
       Shift_Start,
       Shift_End,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_Start
                          END,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_End
                          END
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                       CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                   ELSE
                       Shift_Start
               END
           ELSE
               NULL
       END AS Night_Start_Time,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_Start
                          END,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_End
                          END
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               CASE
                   WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                       CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                   ELSE
                       Shift_End
               END
           ELSE
               NULL
       END AS Night_Shift_End,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_Start
                          END,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_End
                          END
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               DATEDIFF( S,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_Start
                          END,
                          CASE
                              WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                                  CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                              ELSE
                                  Shift_End
                          END
                        ) / 3600.0
           ELSE
               0.0
       END AS Night_Shift_Duration
FROM #Shift;
```

This statement starts by using the following segment to choose the night shift start time (as opposed to the shift start time)...

```
CASE
    WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
        CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
    ELSE
        Shift_Start
END
```

This segment extracts the `TIME` component of `Shift_Start` and tests to see if it falls outside the night shift time-frame.  If it does then it extracts the `DATE` component of `Shift_Start` and converts it to a string so that it may concatenate the date with a string representation of the night shift start time.  The joined string is then converted into its equivalent `DATETIME` value.

If the `TIME` component of `Shift_Start` does not fall outside the night shift time-frame, then the value of `Shift_Start` is returned.

The following statement uses a similar logic to determine the night shift end time...

```
CASE
    WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
        CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
    ELSE
        Shift_End
END
```

If the identified night shift end time for a record is more than `1800` seconds (`30` minutes expressed as seconds, allowing for a level of precision by the second) *after* the identified night shift start time for that record, then the fields `Night_Start_Time` and `Night_Shift_End` for that record will be set to their respective night shift times and `Night_Shift_Duration` is set to the difference between them in hours, calculated as the difference in seconds divided by the number of seconds in an hour.

I have tested my statement against a database created using the script you supplied (thank you for that), with the desired results being achieved.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Appendix 1**

The following statement was run against the sample database to allow for further testing...

```
INSERT INTO #Shift
VALUES ( 7,
         '20170522 05:31:00',
         '20170522 22:01:00' ),
       ( 8,
         '20170522 04:31:00',
         '20170522 22:01:00' );
```

**Appendix 2**

The following statement is a variation of the statement above that uses a subquery to determine the values of `Night_Start_Time` and `Night_Shift_End` for each record *without* consideration of the difference between the two.  The values so generated are used by the main query to determine the final values of `Night_Start_Time`, `Night_Shift_End` and `Night_Shift_Duration`.

I am not certain which is more efficient.

```
SELECT Eid,
       Shift_Start,
       Shift_End,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          Night_Start_Time,
                          Night_Shift_End
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               Night_Start_Time
           ELSE
               NULL
       END AS Night_Start_Time,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          Night_Start_Time,
                          Night_Shift_End
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               Night_Shift_End
           ELSE
               NULL
       END AS Night_Shift_End,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF( S,
                          Night_Start_Time,
                          Night_Shift_End
                        ) >= 1800 THEN
               DATEDIFF( S,
                          Night_Start_Time,
                          Night_Shift_End
                       ) / 3600.0
           ELSE
               0.0
       END AS Night_Shift_Duration
FROM ( SELECT Eid,
              Shift_Start,
              Shift_End,
              CASE
                  WHEN CAST( Shift_Start AS TIME ) BETWEEN '05:30:01' AND '22:00:00' THEN
                      CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 22:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                  ELSE
                      Shift_Start
              END Night_Start_Time,
              CASE
                  WHEN CAST( Shift_End AS TIME ) BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '22:29:59' THEN
                      CAST( ( CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS VARCHAR ) + ' 06:00' ) AS DATETIME )
                  ELSE
                      Shift_End
              END Night_Shift_End
       FROM #Shift
     ) AS shiftTimesFinder;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
           CASE
               WHEN DATEPART( HH, Shift_Start ) >= 22 OR DATEPART( HH, Shift_Start ) <= 6 THEN
                   IIF( DATEPART( HH, Shift_Start ) > 6, 6 + ( DATEPART( HH, Shift_Start ) - 22 ), ( 6 - DATEPART( HH, Shift_Start ) ) )
           END Night_Shift_StartTrue,
           CASE
               WHEN DATEPART( HH, Shift_End ) >= 22 OR DATEPART( HH, Shift_End ) <= 6 THEN
                   IIF( DATEPART( HH, Shift_End ) > 6, ( DATEPART( HH, Shift_End ) - 22 ), ( DATEPART( HH, Shift_End ) + 2 ) )
           END Night_Shift_EndTrue
    FROM #shift
)
SELECT Eid,
       Shift_Start,
       Shift_End,
       CASE
           WHEN ISNULL( Night_Shift_StartTrue, 0 ) > 30 OR ISNULL( Night_Shift_EndTrue, 0 ) > 30 THEN
               IIF( ISNULL( Night_Shift_StartTrue, 0 ) > 0, Shift_Start, DATEADD( HOUR, 22, CAST( CAST( Shift_End AS DATE ) AS DATETIME ) ) )
       END Night_Start_Time,
       CASE
           WHEN ISNULL( Night_Shift_StartTrue, 0 ) > 30 OR ISNULL( Night_Shift_EndTrue, 0 ) > 30 THEN
               IIF( ISNULL( Night_Shift_EndTrue, 0 ) > 0, Shift_End, DATEADD( HOUR, 6, CAST( CAST( Shift_Start AS DATE ) AS DATETIME ) ) )
       END Night_End_Time,
       CONCAT( ISNULL( ( Night_Shift_StartTrue / 60 ), 0 ), ' hr ', Night_Shift_StartTrue % 60, ' mins' ) Night_Shift_StartTrue,
       CONCAT( ISNULL( ( Night_Shift_EndTrue / 60), 0 ), ' hr ', Night_Shift_EndTrue % 60, ' mins' ) Night_Shift_EndTrue
FROM CTE
```

---

Fourth and Fifth Entry has nightshift timing under start as well as the end time, choose the apt one as per your expectation.

Comment: Its sql-server 2008, no IIF

Comment: Use case instead off IIF

Comment: Case when isnull(Night_Shift_StartTrue,0)>30 or isnull(Night_Shift_EndTrue,0)>30 
then 
  Case when isnull(Night_Shift_StartTrue,0)>0 
       then Shift_Start 
    Else dateadd(Hour,22,cast(cast(shift_End as date) as datetime))
       End  
End Night_Start_Time,
case when isnull(Night_Shift_StartTrue,0)>30 or isnull(Night_Shift_EndTrue,0)>30 
then 
  Case when isnull(Night_Shift_EndTrue,0)>0 
       then Shift_End 
    else dateadd(Hour,6,cast(cast(shift_start as date) as datetime)) 
       End 
End Night_End_Time

Comment: You can improve the quality of your Question by editing it to replace the instances of  `IIF()` in the CTE query and to replace the `Night_Start_Time` and `Night_End_Time` selection fragments with the code from the previous comment.  Also, in the CTE query `Night_Shift_StartTrue` and `Night_Shift_EndTrue` are assigned an integer number of *hours*, but the outer query thinks that they are a number of *minutes*.  Also, your statement handles relies upon all times being an integer number of hours - times like `05:45:00` are poorly handled.  Also, could do with a better explanation.